# Changing Gmail's settings to displays a user’s email rather than their name

Tags: gmail, google-talk

I want the email to be shown when chatting with friends in Gmail or Google Talk.

I feel it is more secure to see their email address, as users can change their names and even have the same name as others.

So I need the email address to be shown instead of the name when chatting with friends in Gmail.

Is this possible? And if yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be a way to do this via built-in settings (I'm unsure if there are any plugins/extensions which may do this), but you can see the email addresses with a quick check.

In Gchat, simply hover over the person's name in the chat list for a few seconds. Their contact card will pop up. Their email address is displayed on the second line, below their name.

[image: gchat]

Gtalk works identically. Hover over the name in the contact list and the contact card will pop up. Their email address is displayed in the bottom left of the window.

[image: gtalk]

Comment: Thanks but not possible to check email id every time, I need email id instead of there name

Comment: is this possible? @phantom42